# Our splunk instance reports a DNS query type of "ALL" which doesn't exist?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My work splunk instance reports a DNS query type of "ALL." As far as I know there is an "ANY" which is actually a "*" and the pulls cached records for that host, and there is an AXFR (zone transfer) that pulls all records for a domain...

So I've tried to check the RFC's for BIND 9 DNS and etc but the word "all" is so common I'm struggling to root cause this. So:

Question 1:

> Is there a DNS "ALL" request in any version of DNS?

Sub question if the answer to the above is no:

> Why does splunk present this and what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reading too much into it.  "ALL" means all DNS requests of all types.

Comment: Under "questiontype" it says "ALL." That field is the closest to "query_type" I can find on the logs. ...So it's -not- in the search field. Can you elaborate what you mean? That answer is not clear.

Comment: Yeah, so I mis-read the question.  Are you looking the raw data or a dashboard?  If the former, unless there are props.conf settings that are changing values, then Splunk is simply passing on what it got from the DNS server.  Have you checked the vendor's docs to see what "ALL" means to them?  If you're looking at a dashboard, then check the code for that dashboard so see how "ALL" is used.